# String to DateTime Object in Python

Tags: python

I have date in string:

```
mystring = "2013-10-25 07:53:07.367857"
```

Can I convert this string to datetime object?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you want

```
  from datetime import datetime
  datetime.strptime(mystring, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
```